# Proof that absolute value of a random variable is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is this proof correct?:

Proof:

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable on a probability space $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\}$. Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \geq 0$. Then $\{|X| \leq x\} = \{X \leq x \} \cap \{X < -x \}^c$. Since $X$ is a random variable $\{X \leq x \} \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\{X < -x \}^c \in \mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field, the intersection $\{|X| \leq x\} = \{X \leq x \} \cap \{X < -x \}^c$ also belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Thus $|X|$ is a random variable. $\square$

Comment: Looks good! An even simpler approach: The composition of two measurable function is a measurable function. $x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous, therefore measurable. qed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

You also could have argued with this more general statement: If $X$ is a random variable and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is a random variable [assuming you choose the Borel-sigma-algebra on the domain and the range of $f$].

Comment: I think in the definition of  random variable we have an additional assumption namely $P(X<\infty)=1$ or $P(X=\infty)=0$

Comment: @Saty: That is not necessary, a random variable is any measurable function.